# Visual studio not recognized css

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, less

I have strange problem. I downloaded theme. And i entered theme's main folder and opened index html in browser. Everything okey and looks well. Css and javascript loaded correct. Then i copy theme's folder into the my asp.net mvc project (with all folder(inlude css and js folder)). But when i opened index.html with my browser css and javascript not loaded correctly. I dont know why.

My themes folder structure is shown below:

[image]

My themes folder structure in my asp.net mvc project is shown below:

[image]

My html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="themes/less/bootstrap.less">
<script src="themes/js/less/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="themes/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also i tried(~/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="~/themes/less/bootstrap.less">
<script src="~/themes/js/less/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/themes/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And exception:

[image]

Not: It is not working when in asp.net mvc project otherwise it is working.

Comment: Mayme less.js have to be loaded before .less theme file.

Comment: I loaded less.js before .less theme file and error has gone. But my index.html page not look well. Looks like not recognized css . But there is no error.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779625/lesscss-and-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks daniele i added this in my web config and problem resolved:
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
  </staticContent >
</system.webServer>

Comment: @fuat You should make your comment that answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks daniele i added this in my web config and problem resolved:

```
<system.webServer> 
 <staticContent> 
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />    
 </staticContent > 
</system.webServer>
```