# How to make global LESS styles configurable from an MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, less

I have a master *.less file that my other files import - this contains things like the following:

```
@colorOne: blue;
@colorTwo: red;
```

I'm trying to figure out how to update these values from an MVC page.

I'm really stuck here because right now I'm using Web Essentials to compile the CSS from my IDE.  Even if the MVC app can update the values in the less file (which I don't know that it can), I need to somehow trigger the recompile, and then all of my CSS is out of sync with source control.

This leads me to believe the only possible solution is to store configurable styles in the db, but the customer doesn't like this idea because then we might as well scrap LESS (how can we push the values from the db back into the global *less file + recompile?)

Any general guidance here would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you know about `modifyVars` in LESS? depending on what do you want to achieve this may be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the MVC app can update the values in the less file

As i understood you can compile (and bundle) less files in your app, see:  [ASP.Net MVC4 bundle for less files not being rendered when debug set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549455/asp-net-mvc4-bundle-for-less-files-not-being-rendered-when-debug-set-to-false), [Lesscss and ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779625/lesscss-and-asp-net-mvc) etc.

If you can't update the values in your less file, you can try to 'overwrite' them, see https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Variables#last-declaration-win---even-after-use. (import your current master file in a new file, redefine @colorOne in this file and compile this)

> all of my CSS is out of sync with source control

When all your CSS has been build with LESS and code as mentioned above, the resulting CSS will be a compiled end product which is not under source control